# Get Count of order on every day of week

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Hi I have a model like :

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeginKey(User)
    startDatatime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I want count orders on Each week day . like On all Mondays count of orders and on all week days etc

**EDIT**

Is that a good way to do that ?

```
 data = []
        weekdays = {'Sunday': 1, 'Monday': 2, 'Tuesday': 3, 'Wednesday': 4, ' Thursday': 5,
                    'Friday': 6, 'Saturday': 7}
        for day, value in weekdays.items():
            weekly_tasks_count = Task.objects.filter(
                todo_list__for_user=request.user,
                creation_date_time__week_day=value).count()
            data.append({day: weekly_tasks_count})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to tidy up your code a little bit more.

```py
WEEKDAYS = {
  'Sunday': 1, 
  'Monday': 2, 
  'Tuesday': 3, 
  'Wednesday': 4, 
  'Thursday': 5,
  'Friday': 6, 
  'Saturday': 7
}
  
data = [
  {
    day: Task.objects.filter(
      todo_list__for_user=request.user,
      creation_date_time__week_day=value).count()
  )} 
  for day, value in WEEKDAYS.items()
]
```

One more possible improvement is to build up the `WEEKDAYS` dictionary from values found in the `datetime` module, but so far having it defined your way doesn't harm readability.